# Flutter: CustomPainter difficulties with offset determination

Tags: flutter

I am trying to achieve the following in Flutter but I fail

```
<style>
   #square {
      display: block;
      width:  300px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   #square img {
     position: absolute;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <div id="square">
     <img src="whatever.jpg" style="left:-5%;top:-10%;width:130%" />
   </div>
</body>
```

The idea is to "pan/zoom" an image so that it does not depend on the container's dimensions (that's why I put a style with percentages).

I tried to achieve this through a CustomPainter but I can't figure out the paint Rectangle to pass to the paintImage() method.  It seems like the canvas top left corner does not correspond to the top left corner of the container to draw to.

Here is the partial code:

```
class _ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  const _ImagePainter({this.image, this.leftPercent, this.topPercent, this.widthPercent});

  final ui.Image image;
  final double leftPercent;
  final double topPercent;
  final double widthPercent;

  //
  //  How to compute the theOffset ???
  //
  Offset offset;


  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: offset & (size * widthPercent), image: image, fit:BoxFit.contain, alignment: Alignment.topLeft);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_ZoomableImagePainter old) {
    return old.image != image || old.leftPercent != leftPercent || old.topPercent != topPercent  || old.widthPercent != widthPercent;
  }
}
```

I have now been struggling for hours....

Could anyone help me ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out...

Here is the code:

```
class _ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  const _ImagePainter({this.image, this.leftPercent, this.topPercent, this.widthPercent});

  final ui.Image image;
  final double leftPercent;
  final double topPercent;
  final double widthPercent;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //
    //  This is how to compute both offset and paintRectangle
    //
    double imageWidhHeightRatio = image.width.toDouble() / image.height.toDouble();
    Offset offset = new Offset(leftPercent * size.width, topPercent * size.height);
    Rect imagePaintRect = new Rect.fromLTRB(offset.dx, offset.dy, offset.dx + size.width * widthPercent, offset.dy + size.height * widthPercent / imageWidthHeightRatio);

    paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: imagePaintRect, image: image, fit:BoxFit.fill, alignment: Alignment.topLeft);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_ZoomableImagePainter old) {
    return old.image != image || old.leftPercent != leftPercent || old.topPercent != topPercent  || old.widthPercent != widthPercent;
  }
}
```

The tricks were:
1. We need to consider the rectangle to paint the image to, as an area with its dimensions rescaled to the destination area.
2. To paint the image, using the BoxFit.fill

I hope that this will help.

Enjoy !